# Type inference of 'auto' when using range-for loop in multidimensional arrays

Tags: c++, c++11

After `int ia[3][4]{}`, I run:

```
for(auto row : ia) // row should be type int*
    for(int *j = std::begin(*row); j!= end(*row); ++j) // error!!
        std::cout << *j << std::endl;
```

According to C++ primer 5th:

> Because row is not a reference, when the compiler
>   initializes row it will convert each array element (like any other
>   object of array type)
>   to a pointer to that array’s first element

So if row is a pointer to `ia`'s first element, then why does the error happen?

Many thanks!

UPDATE:

```
ch339.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
ch339.cpp:10:31: error: no matching function for call to ‘begin(int*&)’
        for (int *j = begin(row); j!= end(row); ++j )
                               ^
ch339.cpp:10:31: note: candidates are:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/basic_string.h:42:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/string:52,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/iostream:39,
                 from ch339.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/initializer_list:89:5: note: template<class _Tp> constexpr const _Tp* std::begin(std::initializer_list<_Tp>)
     begin(initializer_list<_Tp> __ils) noexcept
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.9/initializer_list:89:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
ch339.cpp:10:31: note:   mismatched types ‘std::initializer_list<_Tp>’ and ‘int*’
        for (int *j = begin(row); j!= end(row); ++j )
                               ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/string:51:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/iostream:39,
                 from ch339.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/range_access.h:87:5: note: template<class _Tp, long unsigned int _Nm> _Tp* std::begin(_Tp (&)[_Nm])
     begin(_Tp (&__arr)[_Nm])
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/range_access.h:87:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
ch339.cpp:10:31: note:   mismatched types ‘_Tp [_Nm]’ and ‘int*’
        for (int *j = begin(row); j!= end(row); ++j )
                               ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/string:51:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/iostream:39,
                 from ch339.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/range_access.h:58:5: note: template<class _Container> decltype (__cont.begin()) std::begin(const _Container&)
     begin(const _Container& __cont) -> decltype(__cont.begin())
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/range_access.h:58:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/range_access.h: In substitution of ‘template<class _Container> decltype (__cont.begin()) std::begin(const _Container&) [with _Container = int*]’:
ch339.cpp:10:31:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/range_access.h:58:5: error: request for member ‘begin’ in ‘__cont’, which is of non-class type ‘int* const’
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/range_access.h:48:5: note: template<class _Container> decltype (__cont.begin()) std::begin(_Container&)
     begin(_Container& __cont) -> decltype(__cont.begin())
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/range_access.h:48:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/range_access.h: In substitution of ‘template<class _Container> decltype (__cont.begin()) std::begin(_Container&) [with _Container = int*]’:
ch339.cpp:10:31:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/range_access.h:48:5: error: request for member ‘begin’ in ‘__cont’, which is of non-class type ‘int*’
ch339.cpp:10:45: error: no matching function for call to ‘end(int*&)’
        for (int *j = begin(row); j!= end(row); ++j )
                                             ^
ch339.cpp:10:45: note: candidates are:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/basic_string.h:42:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/string:52,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/iostream:39,
                 from ch339.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/initializer_list:99:5: note: template<class _Tp> constexpr const _Tp* std::end(std::initializer_list<_Tp>)
     end(initializer_list<_Tp> __ils) noexcept
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.9/initializer_list:99:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
ch339.cpp:10:45: note:   mismatched types ‘std::initializer_list<_Tp>’ and ‘int*’
        for (int *j = begin(row); j!= end(row); ++j )
                                             ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/string:51:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/iostream:39,
                 from ch339.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/range_access.h:97:5: note: template<class _Tp, long unsigned int _Nm> _Tp* std::end(_Tp (&)[_Nm])
     end(_Tp (&__arr)[_Nm])
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/range_access.h:97:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
ch339.cpp:10:45: note:   mismatched types ‘_Tp [_Nm]’ and ‘int*’
        for (int *j = begin(row); j!= end(row); ++j )
                                             ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/string:51:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/iostream:39,
                 from ch339.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/range_access.h:78:5: note: template<class _Container> decltype (__cont.end()) std::end(const _Container&)
     end(const _Container& __cont) -> decltype(__cont.end())
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/range_access.h:78:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/range_access.h: In substitution of ‘template<class _Container> decltype (__cont.end()) std::end(const _Container&) [with _Container = int*]’:
ch339.cpp:10:45:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/range_access.h:78:5: error: request for member ‘end’ in ‘__cont’, which is of non-class type ‘int* const’
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/range_access.h:68:5: note: template<class _Container> decltype (__cont.end()) std::end(_Container&)
     end(_Container& __cont) -> decltype(__cont.end())
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/range_access.h:68:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/range_access.h: In substitution of ‘template<class _Container> decltype (__cont.end()) std::end(_Container&) [with _Container = int*]’:
ch339.cpp:10:45:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/range_access.h:68:5: error: request for member ‘end’ in ‘__cont’, which is of non-class type ‘int*’

shell returned 1

Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Comment: This looks like a good opportunity to learn how to understand your C++ compiler's error messages. C++ compilers are notorious for nearly incomprehensible errors. But the cold hard truth is that unless someone plans to always to go to some web site and ask strangers for help when they can't understand the reason for their compilation error, they must learn how to unravel compilation errors. There's a very good chance that for a simple situation like this one, your compiler's error actually tells you what it thinks, and why this is the case. So why don't you show what your compiler's saying.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have update the error in details. It is really long and I don't understand it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The type of `row` is deduced to be `int*`.  That means, just like any other `int*`, the compiler doesn't know how big the array it points to is, or even that it's a pointer to the first element of an array at all.  All of that information is lost when an array decays into a pointer to its first element.

If instead you use something like

```
for (auto& row : ia) // <-- NOTE: row is now a reference
    for (int* j = std::begin(row); j != std::end(row); ++j)
        std::cout << *j << '\n';
```

then the type of `row` will be deduced to `int (&)[4]`: reference to an array of 4 `int`s.  The length information is retained, so `std::begin` and `std::end` have the information they need.

---

PS: Just as a note: range-for works by using `std::begin` and `std::end` internally, so the above can be a bit more concisely written as

```
for (auto& row : ia)
    for (auto j : row)
        std::cout << j << '\n';
```

Comment: Thanks! The answer is really clear, I can understand why I should create a pointer like `int (*row)[4]` rather than `int *row` in this case as well. I have update the compile errror in details, but the only thing I can understand is that there is 'no matching function' and 'mismatched type', how can I solve the problem base on those information?

Comment: In this case, "no matching function for call to ‘begin(int*&)’" is more-or-less the extent of the useful information in that error message.  The rest is just a list of what versions of `begin` the compiler found and why they can't be applied to an `int*`.  You could then look at the [documentation for `std::begin`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) and see that there is indeed no overload that could accept a pointer, but there is one that accepts a `T (&)[N]`.

Comment: Your answers really help me a lot! Thanks again!